# knockout.js boolean data-binding issues with radio buttons

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, boolean, observable

I'm currently doing the following to compensate for boolean's not mapping well to radio buttons.  I am stuck binding 1 and 0 to the value (instead of true and false) because of how the fields are read out of the observables.  The value of Pref1/Pref2 come as true/false boolean values from the server.  The key here is I want to not only data-bind the checked value of the radio button to match the true/false in the object, but I also want the boolean value of true/false to be written back into the GraduationClass object.  My compensation code is not only ugly, but not scalable.

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radioGroup" data-bind="checked: Pref1" />Yes
<input type="radio" value="0" name="radioGroup" data-bind="checked: Pref2" />No    
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $root.saveGraduationClass ">Save</a>  

function SiteSettingsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.saveGraduationClass = function(graduationClass) {
        // hack until i get a custom radio button binding
        if (graduationClass.Pref1() == 1) {
            graduationClass.Pref1(true);            
        } else {
            graduationClass.Pref1(false);            
        }  

        if (graduationClass.Pref2() == 1) {
            graduationClass.Pref2(true);
        } else {
            graduationClass.Pref2(false);
        }

        // ...ajax call to save graduationClass to the server
    }

function GraduationClass(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}
```

Comment: If it's a "Yes/No" question, isn't it easier to change the form to use checkboxes instead of radio buttons?

Comment: I suppose I could, but theoretically, I'd just like to see how this would be resolved.

Comment: @AdamLevitt - You could write an extender to always convert the value of Pref1/2 to booleans. However I agree with Niko, this just doesn't make sense and contradicts how radio buttons work.

Comment: Usually I agree with the checkbox suggestion, but a) sometimes you don't have a choice because you don't control the UX design; or b) sometimes there is something more to the story. Here's an example I worked on recently where the radio buttons were a requirement and they made sense: `(O) Use the calculated estimate: 123.50 ( ) Provide an override: [__________]`. The value bound to the radio buttons was a boolean property called "UseOverride".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example from knockoutJs website, that demonstrate how to use radio buttons with 
"checked" attribute:

```
<p>Send me spam: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" /></p>
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
    Preferred flavor of spam:
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
        spamFlavor: ko.observable("almond") // Initially selects only the Almond radio button
    };

    // ... then later ...
    viewModel.spamFlavor("msg"); // Now only Monosodium Glutamate is checked
</script>
```

But I dont understand why you use two objects - "Pref1" and "Pref2" fro one radiobutton group "radioGroup"? In this case you just could use one object as in an example used "spamFlavor".

So, please, describe more ditaily what you want to bind: one radiobuttons group by one selected value, or something else.

Also you could use computed observables to calculate different values, please see [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_zaets/r9jpN/7/).

Comment: See in the title how it mentions binding to **boolean**? From my perspective, this doesn't answer the question asked at all.

Comment: @CarrieKendall, I think author marked it as answered, because he got answer on his question, am I wrong?